# Siting imperative control in react application

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a use case where a control from a third party needs to be hosted in an iframe. Every time it loads there are financial charges. So, letting react control the dom is bad. I've only got a few weeks of react under the belt. I recognize the danger, but not the full solution.

Communication with the imperative API is fine. I read the Netflix blog and that's fine. But I'm missing how you stick something in the tree that you can reference and force REACT to leave alone.

Seems like maybe I want some combination of useREF and useMEMO with no dependencies?

Comment: You can use the ``__dangerouslySetInnerHTML`` prop to render something independent of React

Comment: And that would be an XSS vector if I'm not careful. It might be that this is the only way to do it, but that's a bit surprising....